# Length Linestring in meters with rails - invalid geometry HINT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

I try to find a linestring length in meters

In my controller show :

```
def show
  @track = Track.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @track_length = Track.find_by_sql ["SELECT ST_Length('path') FROM tracks WHERE id = ?", @track.id]
end
```

**My show view :**

```
<p>Track id : <%= @track.id%></p>
<p>Longueur : <%= @track_length %></p>
<p>Linestring : <%= @track.path %></p>
```

**Return :**

PG::InternalError: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry HINT: "pa" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry CONTEXT: SQL function "st_length" statement 1 : SELECT ST_Length('path') FROM tracks WHERE id = 1
What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this a little differently. In your class `Track` add a method as follows:

```
class Track 

  def length 
    @length ||= calculate_length 
  end 

  def calculate_length 
    length_sql = <<-SQL 
      select st_length(path) as length from tracks where id=#{self.id}
    SQL
    Track.connection.execute(length_sql).first["length"]
  end   
end
```

So we memoize the length (remember it). If `@length` is not set, we calculate the length, otherwise we just return the previously calculated value.

And then in your view you can just do something like

```
<p>Track id : <%= @track.id%></p>
<p>Longueur : <%= '%.02f' % @track.length %>m</p>
<p>Longueur : <%= '%.02f' % (@track.length/1000) %>km</p>
```

Comment: I try to do the same things, but I have an error : undefined local variable or method `sql' for #<Track id: nil, length: 254.885050154746>

Comment: Good.... but you must specify ::geography for the path : 
select (st_length(path::geography)/1000) as length from tracks where id=#{self.id} otherwise the function don't return meters but degrees. ;)

Comment: Yes, that depends on the coordinate system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

**In controller :**

```
@track_length = Track.find_by_sql(["SELECT (ST_Length(path::geography)/1000)  AS length FROM tracks WHERE id = ?", @track.id])
```

**In show :**

```
<p>Longueur : <%= number_with_precision(@track_length.first.length, precision: 2) %> kilomètres</p>
```

Maybe there is a better solution, but it works ;)